# Summary functions are restricted to the select and having clauses only

Tags: sql

I want to display the number of project having x applications (in the dataset 1 row = 1 application, thats why I consider 1 ID_Project as 1 application) :

```
SELECT 
(CASE 
      WHEN COUNT(ID_Project) = 1 THEN 'Projects with 1 application'
      WHEN COUNT(ID_Project) = 2 THEN 'Projects with 2 applications'
      WHEN COUNT(ID_Project) = 3 THEN 'Projects with 3 applications'
      ELSE 'Projects with 3+ applications'
END), COUNT(ID_Project)
    FROM TEST2

GROUP BY 
(CASE 
      WHEN COUNT(ID_Project) = 1 THEN 'Projects with 1 application'
      WHEN COUNT(ID_Project) = 2 THEN 'Projects with 2 applications'
      WHEN COUNT(ID_Project) = 3 THEN 'Projects with 3 applications'
      ELSE 'Projects with 3+ applications'
END);
```

I have the following error "Summary functions are restricted to the select and having clauses only". I know that I can't use count in the group by but I think Its mandatory if I want to have categories.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: please tag with database platform

Answer (score 1):

I think you want two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT cnt, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT ID_PROJECT, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM TEST2
      GROUP BY ID_Project
     ) p
GROUP BY cnt
ORDER BY cnt;
```

Sometimes in such a query, I also include `MIN(ID_Project)` and `MAX(ID_Project)` to get example projects.